# Change field value before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the text from the textarea of form with js markdown converter before post

Now I have this code:

```
var message_textarea = $("#message_text");
...    

$('#message-form').submit(function()
{
  message_textarea.val(converter.makeHtml(message_textarea.val()));
})
```

It works, but I would like to change it so that the form isn't display changes in the text box before sending.
How can I do it?

Comment: Instead you could use a hidden input element to send converted data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new `input` of `hidden` type to your `form` :

```
<input type='hidden' id='hidden_message_text' />
```

Then on `submit` fill it with converted data :

```
var hidden_message_textarea = $("#hidden_message_text");

hidden_message_textarea.val(converter.makeHtml(message_textarea.val()));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the content of a textarea will display it on the DOM. You could try to use a separate hidden textarea. Meaning the displayed area contains the normal text and the hidden area contains the markdown.

You also could try to serialize the form, change the content and submit it using ajax all inside the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can avoid Form submission and send data to server via AJAX call.
Here is example from Jquery docs 

<pre>
<form>
  <div><input type="text" name="a" value="1" id="a"></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="b" value="2" id="b"></div>
  <div><input type="hidden" name="c" value="3" id="c"></div>
  <div>
    <textarea name="d" rows="8" cols="40">4</textarea>
  </div>
  <div><select name="e">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select></div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="f" value="8" id="f">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="g">
  </div>
</form>
<script>
   $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
     var data =  $( this ).serializeArray() ;
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '--some-url--',
        data: data,
        success: function(){/* callback*/}
      });
   });
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Submitting form via Ajax helped me.
Thanks to all!